# Plugin conflict in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, datatables, datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-editor

I've been using the [wpDataTables](https://wpdatatables.com/) plugin on my WordPress site. I decided to download the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) + [Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) libraries in order to get more functionality in creating the tables. I however now have a situation where I need both the plugin and libraries to co-exist on the site (whilst I gradually re-create my tables in DataTables). When I load a page I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: DataTable.Editor is not a constructor` and my DataTables tables don't load. I suspect it's because wpDataTables is built on the DataTables library and hence the javascript, css etc are being loaded twice? Can anyone advise on how I can have the two 'plugins' co-exist on the site please? Thank you

Comment: Could you please share a bit of your code so we can better understand.
Do you include the `dataTables.editor.js` already?

Comment: I recommend you add more information to your question. Like the HTML source code of the page, which contains the parts from which the table and js files are called.